# Toward or towards in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

Which of these sentences sounds correct?

> These dynamics are used to explain the convergence **toward** an equilibrium state.
>
> These dynamics are used to explain the convergence **towards** an equilibrium state.

I have been reading a lot of posts, but I still have doubts. Need your suggestions :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many years ago, on `alt.usage.english`,
somebody asked about *toward* and *towards*,
and included *beside* and *besides* for good measure.

[This was my answer](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/besides.html).
Basically, they're both correct, and there's no difference.
This is not true of *beside* and *besides*, however.

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps "towards" has to do with first part of a path between two things and "toward" concerns the other end of the path.  If the path is a straight line, it doesn't make any difference.  If the path has bends, it might.  I don't see a difference for your example.